# Android keep scroll relative position when changing text size

Tags: java, android, position, scrollview, text-size

I'm working on a project containing a linear layout consisting of many text views, all wrapped by a scroll view.
The User has the option of changing text size within a dialog. I would like the user's relative scroll position to be kept when the text size changes.

For example: Say we have 10 text views and the user is currently scrolled to the middle of the third one. I would like the user to still be scrolled more or less to the middle of the third one after changing the text size.

I've tried doing this:

```
        double scrollViewHeight = sv.getChildAt(0).getBottom() - sv.getHeight();
        double getScrollY = sv.getScrollY();
        double scrollPosition = (getScrollY / scrollViewHeight) * 100d;


        // the relevant part of this chunk is the changing of the text size
        int textSize = ++((SettingsDialogFragment) dialog).currentTextSize;
        if(textSize > 100) --((SettingsDialogFragment) dialog).currentTextSize;
        for(int i=0; i<ll.getChildCount();++i){
            TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(i);
            tv.setTextSize(textSize);
        }


        double newSVHeigth = sv.getChildAt(0).getBottom() - sv.getHeight();
        sv.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) ((int) scrollPosition*newSVHeigth));
```

So basically getting the proportion scrolled and scrolling that proportion within the new height.
The problem is **newSVHeigth** gets the same value as **scrollViewHeight** and they would only change the next time the function is called (a listener to a button click).
So the scroll view only reacts to the changes after this block of code is finished.
On that *next time*, **sv.getChildAt(0).getBottom()** is getting updated but **sv.getHeight()**. I'm not sure why that is but **sv.getChildAt(0).getBottom() - sv.getHeight()** is seeming to give the correct result anyway..

Is there an easier way to do this?
If not, where would the new **scrollViewHeight** be updated and how can I listen to the change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found this solution:
I defined a LayoutChangeListener on the last item of the list of text views.

```
text_views_list.get(text_views_list.size()-1)
.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                double scrollViewHeight = oldBottom - sv.getHeight();
                double getScrollY = sv.getScrollY();
                double scrollPosition = (getScrollY / scrollViewHeight);
                double newSVHeigth = bottom - sv.getHeight();
                sv.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) (scrollPosition*newSVHeigth));
                 }
 });
```

This way whenever I change the text size and the layout changes the scroll is updated.